# How to like facebook post from my webpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

I have a webpage, and facebook page. I would like to have a "like" button that wouldn´t like the facebook page but the last post I made on the facebook page. Is this possible?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

sorry but having an external like button pointing to a single facebook content is not possible at the moment. Although there are codes in the [Graph API: Publishing](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) documentation that relate to this.

Using the said code can make users (who authorized you app) like a content, just like what you are asking for, but I've tried this before and it says that the application needs to be white-listed. I've researched more into this matter and a few more people experienced this as well.

More references:

www.insidefacebook.com/2010/10/08/causes-whitelisted-like-pages-2/
bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=10714